# LilyPond - how to write a basic makefile

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond, engraving

During the last years I tought myself to write scores using [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org) and furthermore to make file handling easier by using [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) scripts.
Recently I started a project a little bigger than only one or two pages and once again I came across the article about [Makefiles](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/make-and-makefiles.en.html) in the [LilyPond Documentary](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/index.en.html).

Even though reading this article it was kinda hard for me to grasp the actual technique behind the template `Makefile` also because the article does not supply the file repository it is working with.

So I though to take the time to make up an example project to ask, how a `Makefile` in this scenario could look like. How I would build it step by step and how I actually run the Makefile. (**Edit:** referring to a [make man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make) I got my understanding as far as being able to say that one uses `make` as interpreter like `bash` on a `shell-script.sh`. The command then simply looks like `make -f Makefile` run in the root directory of the project.)

---

The **Project** has a file-structure like this:

```
├── Book.ly
├── Book.pdf
├── global-files
│   ├── copyright.ily
│   ├── Frontpage.ily
│   ├── header.ily
│   └── paper.ily
├── input-files-voiceI
│   ├── Nr_01-voiceI.ily
│   ├── Nr_02-voiceI.ily
│   └── Nr_03-voiceI.ily
├── input-files-voiceII
│   ├── Nr_01-voiceII.ily
│   ├── Nr_02-voiceII.ily
│   └── Nr_03-voiceII.ily
├── README.md
├── single-pages-voiceI
│   ├── MIDI
│   │   ├── Score-Nr_01-voiceI.midi
│   │   ├── Score-Nr_02-voiceI.midi
│   │   └── Score-Nr_03-voiceI.midi
│   ├── PDF
│   │   ├── Score-Nr_01-voiceI.pdf
│   │   ├── Score-Nr_02-voiceI.pdf
│   │   └── Score-Nr_03-voiceI.pdf
│   ├── Score-Nr_01-voiceI.ly
│   ├── Score-Nr_02-voiceI.ly
│   └── Score-Nr_03-voiceI.ly
├── single-pages-voiceI_a_II
│   ├── MIDI
│   │   ├── Score-I_u_II_Nr_01.midi
│   │   ├── Score-I_u_II_Nr_02.midi
│   │   └── Score-I_u_II_Nr_03.midi
│   ├── PDF
│   │   ├── Score-I_u_II_Nr_01.pdf
│   │   ├── Score-I_u_II_Nr_02.pdf
│   │   └── Score-I_u_II_Nr_03.pdf
│   ├── Score-I_u_II_Nr_01.ly
│   ├── Score-I_u_II_Nr_02.ly
│   └── Score-I_u_II_Nr_03.ly
└── single-pages-voiceII
    ├── MIDI
    │   ├── Score-Nr_01-voiceII.midi
    │   ├── Score-Nr_02-voiceII.midi
    │   └── Score-Nr_03-voiceII.midi
    ├── PDF
    │   ├── Score-Nr_01-voiceII.pdf
    │   ├── Score-Nr_02-voiceII.pdf
    │   └── Score-Nr_03-voiceII.pdf
    ├── Score-Nr_01-voiceII.ly
    ├── Score-Nr_02-voiceII.ly
    └── Score-Nr_03-voiceII.ly
```

---

The **input-files** of both voices have a format like this:

```
\relative c {
  \clef bass
  \time 3/4
  \key c major

  c4( d e f      | %01
  g1) \bar "|."  | %02
}
```

---

The **Score** files have the purpose to be compiled for output of **PDF** and **MIDI.** and simply look like this (despite the fact that the `Scores` for two systems contain another `Staff`):

```
\version "2.18.2"

#(set-default-paper-size "a4")
#(set-global-staff-size 22)

\include "../global-files/header.ily"

\score {
  \new StaffGroup = "" \with {
    instrumentName = \markup { \bold \huge { \larger "1." }}
  }
  <<
    \new Staff = "celloI" \with { midiInstrument = #"cello" }

    \include "../input-files-voiceI/Nr_01-voiceI.ily"
  >>
  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

---

The **Book** part is the part I'm still pretty unhappy with. I would prefer this pretty simple with just using the `Score*.ly` files as `\includes`, but I get problems with the `\includes` that are already in the `Score.ly` files, since they do not *only* contain the `\score` block to be compileable by them selfs.

Well I could use a `\book` with setting a book output name like `\bookOutputSuffix "OutputName"`, but then my `Book.ly` would become a massive file, taking quite a long time to be compiled, even for a small change on a single piece.

So right now my `Book.ly` file has the following format and the only purpose to compile the whole book with two voices in two staffs, but with all pieces, here 01-03:

```
\version "2.18.2"

#(set-default-paper-size "a4")
#(set-global-staff-size 22)

\include "./global-files/paper.ily"

\book {

  \include "./global-files/Frontpage.ily"

  %%%% Score Number: 1 ==================================%%%%

  \score {
    \new StaffGroup = "" \with {
      instrumentName = \markup { \bold \huge { \larger "1." }}}
    <<
      \new Staff = "voiceI" \with { midiInstrument = #"voice" }
      \include "./input-files-voiceI//Nr_01-voiceI.ily"
      \new Staff = "voiceII" \with { midiInstrument = #"voice" }
      \include "./input-files-voiceII//Nr_01-voiceII.ily"
    >>
    \layout {
      \printTupletBow
    }
  }

  %%%% Score Number: 2 ==================================%%%%

  \score {
    \new StaffGroup = "" \with {
      instrumentName = \markup { \bold \huge { \larger "2." }}}
    <<
      \new Staff = "voiceI" \with { midiInstrument = #"voice" }
      \include "./input-files-voiceI//Nr_02-voiceI.ily"
      \new Staff = "voiceII" \with { midiInstrument = #"voice" }
      \include "./input-files-voiceII//Nr_02-voiceII.ily"
    >>
    \layout {}
  }

  %%%% Score Number: 3 ==================================%%%%

  \score {
    \new StaffGroup = "" \with {
      instrumentName = \markup { \bold \huge { \larger "3." }}}
    <<
      \new Staff = "voiceI" \with { midiInstrument = #"voice" }
      \include "./input-files-voiceI//Nr_03-voiceI.ily"
      \new Staff = "voiceII" \with { midiInstrument = #"voice" }
      \include "./input-files-voiceII//Nr_03-voiceII.ily"
    >>
    \layout {}
  }
}
```

---

**My workflow is the following:**

1. I write the input files: `input-file.ily`
2. I run a `bash-script.sh` that creates the compileable `Score.ly` files from the `input-files/*.ily`
3. I run a `bash-script.sh` that creates the compileable `Book.ly` file
   from the `input-files/*.ily`
4. I compile the `Score.ly` files one by one or run a simple `for file in *.ly; do lilypond "$file"; done` loop, but in each of the three Score directories. I use a script to move the PDF and MIDI files into their corresponding folders.
5. I simply run `lilypond` to compile the `Book.ly` file.

DONE

---

The actual project this question is asked for can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/nathanaelmeister/Lee-_Sebastian_-_Op.70_-_40_Easy_Etudes_for_Cello)

---

**Update 1:**

My system:

```
    Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
              Kernel: Linux 5.3.0-2-686-pae
        Architecture: x86
        GNU LilyPond: 2.18.2
My Editor - GNU Nano: 4.5
      Guake Terminal: 3.6.3
            GNU Make: 4.2.1
```

I added my `shell-scripts` to a separate [Git-Repository](https://github.com/nathanaelmeister/LilyPond_Bashscripts.git)

---

**Update 2:**

This is a very simplified chart of the dependencies. Assuming there was only one `voice`:

```
./infiles/                        
  infile{01..03}.ily -------------> ./Book.ly ===> Book.pdf
     |                                 ^ ^ ^
     *---------> Scores{01..03}.ly === | | |=====> Score{01..03}.pdf
                      ^  ^         === | | |=====> Score{01..03}.midi
                      |  |             | | |
./global-files/       |  |             | | |
  header.ily    ------*  |             | | |
  copyright.ily ---------+-------------* | |
  Frontpage.ily -------------------------* |
  paper.ily     ---------------------------*
```

Comment: Do you have the bash-script.sh files available anywhere? I'm having some difficulty grokking the whole procedure.

Comment: Also do inform abt OS and your editor of choice

Comment: FYI: I updated my answer to provide some more context and a brief technical description of the mechanics.

Comment: This question was being discussed in [the meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/is-this-question-on-topic?cb=1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Invocation

`make` will search the current directory for a file named `Makefile` or `makefile`, so it's often simplest to name it one of these two choices and then invoke with the simple command:

```
$ make
```

If you use the uppercase 'M' then the file will usually be listed at the top according to alphabetical or collation order.

### Rules

`make` operates by using rules for how to create an output from an input. The format for a rule is the target followed by a colon, then a space delimited list of dependencies, followed by commands indented with TAB.

```
target: dependencies
    commands
```

The target or dependencies can be filenames or symbols that correspond to other rules.

If you don't specify a target on the command line, it will invoke the first rule it encounters. So a common technique is to make the first rule a "dummy" rule which doesn't produce a file but simply collects all the steps or outputs together. Eg.

```
all: output1
```

Invoking `make` with this makefile will try to create `output1` if it doesn't exist. If there's a rule for creating `output1` later in the makefile it will use that.

For your case, I suggest making a top level rule to create `Score.ly` and `Book.ly`

```
all: Score.ly Book.ly
```

### Pattern rules

To replace your shell loop, you can use a pattern rule.

```
%.pdf: %.ly
    lilypond $^
```

This rule says: *To make a .pdf file, run `lilypond` on the corresponding .ly file*.

***Note that the command to execute must start with a literal TAB character.*** The `%^` variable refers to the input file mentioned above. Other useful variables are `$@` for the target, and `$<` for the first input if there are more than one.

This handles just part of your shell loop, defining the transformation from an input file to an output file. For the other task of generating a list of files, there are some special variables available in GNU make for this.

```
inputs= $(notdir $(wildcard ./*.ly))
bases= $(basename $(inputs))
outputs= $(patsubst %,%.pdf,$(bases))
```

After these definitions, you can use `$(outputs)` as a dependency in a rule, like:

```
pdfs: $(outputs)
    mkdir -p PDF
    mv *.pdf PDF
    mkdir -p MIDI
    mv *.midi MIDI
```

[This example from the LilyPond docs](https://paste.debian.net/1119187/) shows that you can put multiple targets to the left of the colon, so you can account for both types of files produced by LilyPond which my example here doesn't do. ***Again, each of these commands must be indented with a bona fide ASCII TAB character.***

### For very simple cases

You can use a makefile just to collect one or more shell scripts together, ignoring much of the complexity of rules and dependencies if your situation is very simple.

For one project where I made a bunch of .abc files in a single directory, the whole thing is handled by a single rule:

```
all:
    for f in `ls *.abc` ;               \
    do ../abcm2ps -O $${f%.abc}.ps $$f ; \
       ps2pdf $${f%.abc}.ps ;           \
    done ;
    zip -r evildead.zip *.pdf
```

Comment: That didn't work. Trying <tty><pre>.

Comment: Works now. However a semantically loaded initial tab is so unnatural, not just to humans but even well-meaning editors that a stronger caveat may be in order??

Comment: True. That's how `make` has always worked. But I'll try to flag it more loudly and more often as I fill out the answer.

Comment: [I found this](https://paste.debian.net/1119187/) in the [LilyPond Docs](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/make-and-makefiles.en.html) looks like the way to handle both formats **PDF** *and* **MIDI**, as far as I can tell from my `bash` knowledge it also looks like they use an `if statement` to find out weather the files exist or not and then run the `mv` command on it.

Comment: Instead of `lilypond $^`, I would use `lilypond $<`. This lets you use `\include` and specify the dependencies in the makefile.

Comment: @Rusi The lore (tm) has it that the issue with the tabs was noticed just weeks after the utility was first released (in the 1970s) and wasn't changed because there were already more than a dozen users who would have been inconvenienced by the change.

Comment: @luserdroog I added a chart :-)

Answer (score 5):

[luser droog’s answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/92637) gives a good overview of `make` itself. Here’s an
example of how to apply that to a real-world Lilypond project with the
following characteristics:

- Multiple parts: piano, bassoon, etc.
- Multiple movements.
- Multiple desired outputs: a single “master” (conductor) score, a
  master score for each movement, and a part score for each
  instrument.
- Both PDF and MIDI outputs.
- Common definitions (macros) for both music and presentation.

For instance, if your `Book.ly` file includes your `Nr_01-voiceI.ily`
file, which in turn includes your `macros.ily` shared definitions file,
then if `macros.ily` is changed, your Makefile needs to know that it
needs to recompile `Book.ly` to update `Book.pdf`.

On the othre hand, if you change just one part, it is very convenient to
be able to write `make parts` and have Make *only* recompile the part
that was changed, rather than wasting time recompiling all the others.
And, if you just want to listen to a segment, you should be able to
`make midi` to skip the slow typesetting and only re-do the necessary
sequencing.

I’ve written a shell script to generate a Makefile that has all these
properties. In particular, it automatically **traverses the `\include`
graph** of your project to figure out which Lilypond files depend on
which others, and will incur the minimal set of recompilations for any
particular change. You just tell it what “main files” you have, and
which ones you want in PDF and/or MIDI form, and it will do the rest.

Here’s the script:
https://github.com/MutopiaProject/MutopiaProject/blob/918971593735f2dbf4864f289767b8d59a7d950e/ftp/MozartWA/KV488/Mozart-KV488/Mozart-KV488-lys/create_makefile.sh

Here’s an example of the output `Makefile`:
https://github.com/MutopiaProject/MutopiaProject/blob/918971593735f2dbf4864f289767b8d59a7d950e/ftp/MozartWA/KV488/Mozart-KV488/Mozart-KV488-lys/Makefile

The core mechanism is to create a [secondary target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) for each Lilypond
file, which I’ve called its “lydep” (“Lilypond dependencies”) file, such
that a file’s lydep is dirty if and only if any of the file’s transitive
sources is dirty. In practical terms, this means that each lydep target
needs to depend on its source file plus all the lydep targets on which
it has direct `\include` dependencies. Then, Make’s automatic resolution
takes care of the rest.

The script is tailored to a particular project, but you should be able
to keep the core infrastructure in place and customize the `makefile`
function at the bottom to substitute in your project structure.

I’ve written this script for GNU/Linux, and it might need some minor
adjustments for macOS/BSD (e.g., swapping out `readlink -f`), but it’s
pretty straightforward overall. It does require `bash` and GNU `make`
(for secondary targets). I see that you’re on Debian, so it should run
just fine as is.

This is all released under the MIT License. Please feel free to take
whatever you find helpful.

Comment: yuhu man, this is quite a couple of lines to read through. Thanks for the answer, and for sharing your work! <3

Comment: Sure thing. I’ll see if I can explain/summarize the gist of it when I get a chance later today.